# Can a continuous function reach from a finite to infinite values on a closed interval?

Tags: calculus

As asked in the title, I'm curious if a continuous function can span from a finite to an infinite value within a closed interval. I feel as if some function could indeed have infinite values within such an interval (perhaps if it was offset by an arbitrarily large k value), but I'm not sure that within the same interval it could also have finite values and still be continuous. Any ways for this to be possible?

Comment: This question is completely unclear. Are we in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: $[2, \infty)$ is closed, and $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ given by$f(x)=x^2$ certainly goes off to infinity. What do you mean?

Comment: No function $f : [0,1]\to\mathbb R$ can attain "inifinite values", since it maps to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: A continuous function on a closed interval $[a,b]$ achieves an absolute minimum value and an absolute maximum value on the interval (check your textbook for this claim). Hence a continuous function on the interval $[a,b]$ is _bounded_.

Comment: @quasi On a _compact_ interval.

Comment: If you are operating within a closed bounded interval of $\mathbb{R}$ the answer is no. A continuous function on a closed bounded interval is bounded.

Comment: @amsmath: Agreed (and edited).

Comment: My apologies for any lack of clarity in the question, we would indeed be in R as I don't know of any other set that would make a difference. I thought that an interval such as [2, ∞) would be considered open? I'm currently taking Calc I in high school, and it was said that any interval [a,b] is considered closed, while anything with one end of the range with a parenthesis, and by anything where one end is  ∞, is open?

Comment: I suppose a better way of asking the question is: can a function reach from a finite value to an infinite value within a finite interval? (within R)

Answer (score 0):

Closed bounded intervals are compact, and compact spaces are subject to the extreme value theorem: any continuous function attains its extrema. Hence a continuous function on a closed bounded interval does not go to infinity, but instead is bounded by some max.

However closed intervals like $[0,\infty)$ are also closed, but not bounded. Continuous functions on such intervals can go to infinity.

Comment: What is the difference between a closed and a bounded interval? It was my understanding that a closed interval had to have both ends of the range on some finite values which it includes.

Comment: nah, $[0,\infty)$ is closed, but doesn't include a right endpoint. it's only if the interval is closed _and bounded_ that we can conclude it includes both endpoints.

Comment: @EthanO: ziggurism is right. Unfortunately, most standard Calculus textbooks (in the US) promote this misconception. What they call a "closed interval" (in $\mathbb{R}$) should be correctly called a "closed bounded interval". An interval of the form $[a,b]$ is closed and bounded. An interval of the form $[a,+\infty)$ or $(-\infty,a]$ is closed and unbounded, as is $(-\infty,+\infty)$.